# Error while bundle install for idn-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have twitter-text gem in my application.

When I do a bundle install I am getting the below error.

Need to solve it on high priority.

I also went to the github page https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/issues/225

but could not find a solution there.

I tried to install directly using the line below but got the same error.

```
gem install idn-ruby -v '0.1.0'
```

Error

```
Fetching idn-ruby 0.1.0
Installing idn-ruby 0.1.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/inuscg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@idt-two/gems/idn-ruby-0.1.0/ext
/home/inuscg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180427-13217-1wpq9sy.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lidn... no
ERROR: could not find idn library!

  Please install the GNU IDN library or alternatively specify at least one
  of the following options if the library can only be found in a non-standard
  location:
    --with-idn-dir=/path/to/non/standard/location
        or
    --with-idn-lib=/path/to/non/standard/location/lib
    --with-idn-include=/path/to/non/standard/location/include

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/inuscg/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-idn-dir
    --without-idn-dir
    --with-idn-include
    --without-idn-include=${idn-dir}/include
    --with-idn-lib
    --without-idn-lib=${idn-dir}/lib
    --with-idnlib
    --without-idnlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/inuscg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@idt-two/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/idn-ruby-0.1.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/inuscg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@idt-two/gems/idn-ruby-0.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/inuscg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@idt-two/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/idn-ruby-0.1.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing idn-ruby (0.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install idn-ruby -v '0.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  twitter-text was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
    idn-ruby
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to instalo libidn on ur system?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As per the error show in logs
    `ERROR: could not find idn library!`. `idn` library is required to install twitter text. Try to install that first and then install the gem. Try with

```
sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev
sudo apt-get install libidn11-dev
```

Hope this solves your problem.

For mac:

```
brew install libidn
```

Comment: I'm on Apple silicon and I had to set --with-idn-dir to make this work.
`gem install idn-ruby -v '0.1.0' -- --with-idn-dir=$(brew --prefix libidn)`

Answer (score 21):

On a Mac, you can do:

```
$ brew install libidn
```

Comment: This produces a whole pile of errors, but eventually seems to succeed anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Mac OS, then here's how to install `libidn`:

```
$ brew install libidn
```

Answer (score 4):

On Centos 7 I had to install libidn-devel via `yum install libidn-devel`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows and facing same error, then try

> #### Instruction for Windows
>
> - Get the appropriate build of GNU LibIDN Library from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/)
> - Unpack it where you prefer (e.g. `c:\tmp\libs\libidn`)
> - Add option to bundler config 
>     `BUNDLE_BUILD__IDN-RUBY: "--with-idn-dir=C:/tmp/libs/libidn/"`
> - Launch `bundler install`

As for me I used `libidn-1.33-win64.zip` package

Comment: hi, could you tell me `Add option to bundler config` how to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're required to install LibIDN beforehand, since the gem is just ruby bindings for it.

> **Requirements**
>
> - GNU LibIDN Library
> - Rake to run the tests and generate the documentation
> - RubyGems to produce a Gem package
> - Ruby 1.9.1 or above. Patches welcome to make this work in 1.8.7

The specific download method would depend on your OS, but if it's Ubuntu, try `sudo apt-get install libidn`

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu 16LTS... E: Unable to locate package libidn

Answer (score 0):

On **Os X** with **Homebrew**:

```
gem install idn-ruby -- --with-idn-dir=$(brew --prefix libidn)
```