# Bundle install gives LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, canvas-lms

I'm trying to install [Canvas LMS](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start). As I'm doing the production start for [installing bundler and canvas dependencies](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Production-Start#bundler-and-canvas-dependencies) I first run

```
sudo gem install bundler --version 2.2.19 --default
```

which executes successfully. Then I run

```
bundle _2.2.19_ install --path vendor/bundle
```

which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

Here is what I get when I run gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.7.5 (2021-11-24 patchlevel 203) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby2.7
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/sam/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/2.7.0
     - /home/sam/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.7.0
     - /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all
     - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/rubygems-integration/2.7.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/sam/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
```

And running bundler -v gives me this result:
Bundler version 2.3.25

I'd appreciate any help to solve this load error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. I ran into the exact same issue but was able to fix with the below

`sudo gem install bundler -v '2.2.19'`

then

`bundle _2.2.19_ install --path vendor/bundle`

and was able to complete the installation successfully.

You may likely get an error at the end

> An error occurred while installing idn-ruby (0.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install idn-ruby -v '0.1.4'--source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

You can fix that by following the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055812/error-while-bundle-install-for-idn-ruby)

`sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev libidn11-dev`